# Terminal nodes for each Node in a graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to list all the terminal node with respect to a node in graph, my code does work however in a complicated graph it not working efficiently. AS you can see I am using recursion which is not that efficient while dealing with the complicated graph.

```py
def neighbourt(T,item,st1,list1,list2):
 
    
    for n1 in T.neighbors(item):
        if n1 > item and T.degree(n1)> 1:
            #print(n1)
            st1=st1+neighbourt(T,n1,st1,list1,list2)
            
            
            
        elif n1 > item and T.degree(n1)==1:
            fruit_dictionary1 = dict(zip(list1,list2))
            ab=fruit_dictionary1[n1]
            st1=st1+str(ab)+"_"
            #return st1
            
            
        
    return st1
```

The code is written in python and item is the node and T is the undirected graph.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using networkx graph package?  I expect it would be optimized to perform this type of recursion quickly.  https://www.python-course.eu/networkx.php

Comment: @C.Cooney, yes I am using NetworkX graph package. Is there a way I can get a subgraph of particular node using Networkx.

Comment: By terminal nodes you mean leafs? Could you provide an example input/expected output?

Comment: @abc Yes It means leaf nodes  example   A->B,A->C,B->D,F,C->E, For B I want D and F while for C I want E ...

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the same thing but without recursion:

```py
def neighbourT(graph):
    for node in graph.nodes():
        for n in graph.neighbors(node):
            if n > node and graph.degree(n) == 1:
                print(node,n)
```

E.g for graph T:

```
T = nx.Graph()
T.add_edge("A","B")
T.add_edge("A","C")
T.add_edge("B","D")
T.add_edge("B","F")
T.add_edge("C","E")
```

```
neighbourT(T)
# prints
B D
B F
C E
```